# how to Disable a uibutton in another class without navigating to that

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uibutton

My problem is different here i have a big view(classA) and a small view on it(classB), beside this small view there are four buttons which belongs to class A ,I want to disable those buttons.
here is my code.

**in classB.m**

```
-(void)HideButtons{
      mainView = [[MainViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MainViewController"    bundle:NULL];
    [mainView HidesideBarButtons];
 }
```

**in class B**

```
-(void)HidesideBarButtons{

    self.peBtn.enabled = NO; 

    ByViewBtn.enabled = NO;
    favouriteBtn.enabled = NO;
    settingBtn.enabled = NO;
    ItemButton.enabled = NO;
    addVehBtn.enabled = NO;
    uploadAllBtn.enabled = NO;
    deletevideosBtn.enabled = NO;
    }
```

these buttons are not getting disabled.i'm not navigating to that view(cassA) i'm staying in same class;

Comment: you want to hide or disable..?

Comment: put breakpoint at line self.peBtn.enabled = NO; and see this method is call or not?

Comment: that method is calling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make an object of classA then access the button using that object

```
-(void)HidesideBarButtons{  
ClassA *obj =[[ClassA alloc]init];//Initialize it by your way
UIButton *myBtn=[obj getButton1];
[myBtn setEnabled:FALSE];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I right understand your problem, you need to use **delegate**.

In ClassB.h

---

```
@protocol ClassBDelegate <NSObject>

-(void) hideSideBarButtons;

@interface ClassB: UIViewController {

__unsafe_unretained id<ClassBDelegate> delegate_;

}

@property (nonatomic, assign) id delegate;

-(void)hideButtons;

@end


----------

In ClassB.m


----------


@implementation ClassB

@synthesyze delegate = delegate_;

-(void)hideButtons {

[self.delegate hideSideBarButtons];

}


----------

In class MainViewController you need to sign up for ClassBDelegate event. Use this code in MainViewController.h


----------

@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <ClassBDelegate>
In ClassB.h

@protocol ClassBDelegate

-(void) hideSideBarButtons;

@interface ClassB: UIViewController {

__unsafe_unretained id delegate_;

}

@property (nonatomic, assign) id delegate;

-(void)hideButtons;

@end

In ClassB.m

@implementation ClassB

@synthesyze delegate = delegate_;

-(void)hideButtons {

[self.delegate hideSideBarButtons];

}
```

In class MainViewController you need to sign up for ClassBDelegate event. Use this code in MainViewController.h

```
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController
```

When you init `ClassB` in `MainViewController.m` you need to write:

```
[classB setDelegate:self];
```

than you need to write ClassBDelegate method **-`(void) hideSideBarButtons`** in your `MainViewController.m` file and disable all buttons in this method. For example ( in `MainViewController.m`)

---

```
-(void) hideSideBarButtons {

self.peBtn.enabled = NO;

}
```

Hope it helps))